# Getting distinct rows in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get the distinct row values from a table using LINQ. The query i used is

```
 var results = (from statename in dsobject.dbo_statetable select statename).Distinct();
```

It is giving all the rows of the table named "dbo_statetable" but i need only the distinct statename. What should be the query to achieve this?

Its sql equivalent is `select distinct statename from dbo_statetable`

Comment: What column are you trying to select out? This is giving you all the distinct row objects

Comment: @pickles: It looks like he's trying to do the equivalent of the SQL `select distinct statename from dbo_statetable` except in LINQ. So the column name he's trying to select is `statename`.

Comment: @MarkByers. yeah you are correct and i thought "from statename " refers to the column, now got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the property:

```
var results = (from x in dsobject.dbo_statetable select x.Statename).Distinct();
//                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The variable after `from` does not specify the column. It is like a table alias in SQL. Your LINQ statement is roughly equivalent to this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dbo_statetable AS statename
```

Answer (score 0):

`dsobject.dbo_statetable.Select(s => s.statename).Distinct()`